# Javascript, set div color to another divs color

Tags: javascript, css

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('colorsdiv').style.backgroundColor =
    document.getElementById(thediv).style.backgroundColor;
```

I know thediv is valid, because if I do:
`document.getElementById(thediv).style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

it turns red.

If I do:
`alert(document.getElementById(thediv).style.backgroundColor);`
it is `null`.

I also know that it is set to a color in my stylesheet because it displays that way.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the current style of another element, use this:

```
if( typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined")
    getComputedStyle = function(elem) {return elem.currentStyle;};

document.getElementById('colorsdiv').style.backgroundColor
    = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(thediv)).backgroundColor;
```

Comment: If I have a stylesheet: #divname {background-color:black;} how would I reference it in javascript?  If I wanted to do something like document.getElementById('colorsdiv').style.backgroundColor     = style('divname').backgroundColor;

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the javascript that finds the div's color is run **after** the page has completely loaded, e.g. it is in your body section of the html.  This makes sure the page has loaded and rendered the color so the script can retrieve it when it is run.